# Angular is removing my cookies when I try to add XSRF token

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to send XSRF token for every HTTP call inside my HTTP interceptor like this:

```
let token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;

let cloned = req.clone({
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "accept": "*/*"
    })
});

if (token != null) {
    cloned = cloned.clone({
        headers: cloned.headers.append("X-XSRF-TOKEN", token)
    });
}
```

But when token is not null, setting the X-XSRF-TOKEN is removing the cookies from the header.

**Without XSRF configuration:**

[image]

**With XSRF configuration:**
[image]

Where are my cookies ?? And my XSRF token ?

Thank you.

Comment: I have marked your answer as a duplicate of another one : if the problem still persists, feel free to notify me so that I can re-open the question (but honestly you should better create a new one and state that your issue is different)

Comment: when you new HttpHeaders(), it's creating a new HttpHeaders object, I think that is your problem

Comment: @jazza1000 That part of the code is not the problem, it working fine. The issue is when I try to append a something to the header

Comment: @trichetriche The post you linked as duplicate is not the same issue. I simply want to know why it's removing my cookies and the content-type from the request when I try to add the token in the header. I tried the solution proposed in the other post but it changes nothing

Comment: @trichetriche The other post is about reading informations from the response. but I'm try to set stuffs in the request

Comment: It works both ways (from what I have encountered) : Angualr won't send unauthorized headers unless you specify it. Anyway, you said you had tried it, so I'm re-opening your question !